# Multi select in form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to auto populate two drop down fields in form with two rows of same table.
Getting confused on JavaScript

```
<tr>
    <td width="100" valign="top" style="margin-top:0px"><label>Card</label></td>
    <td><select name="cardid" >
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="1000">1000</option>
            <option value="1001">1001</option>
            <option value="1002">1002</option>
            <option value="1003">1003</option>
            <option value="1004">1004</option>
        </select>
    </td> 
</tr>
```

And i want to auto populate select 1000,1001,1002 for Center USA 1003 1004 for Center UK

```
<tr>      
    <td><label>Center</label></td>
    <td><select name="center">
            <option value="USA">USA</option>
            <option value="UK">UK</option>
        </select>
    </td>       
</tr>
```

Any help pl

Comment: Auto populate how exactly, when something is selected ?

Comment: Well, how? Explain it! Also, your markup is invalid.

Comment: say i choose 1000 ot 1001 or 1002 any of these it should auto populate with USA same i choose 1003 or 1004 any of these it should auto populate UK,pl see this

Comment: Like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/RRA5p/

Comment: @adeneo Thanks a lot.Pretty clean and simple code.It worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td width="100" valign="top" style="margin-top:0px"><label>Card</label></td>
    <td><select id="cardid" name="cardid" >
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1000">1000</option>
        <option value="1001">1001</option>
        <option value="1002">1002</option>
        <option value="1003">1003</option>
        <option value="1004">1004</option></select></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label>Center</label> </td>
    <td><select id="center" name="center">
    <option value="USA ">USA </option>
    <option value="UK "> UK </option>
    </select> </td>       
</tr>
```

Javascript:

```
var usa = "1000,1001,1002";
var uk = "1003,1004";
$(function(){
    $('#cardid').change(function(){
        if(usa.indexOf($(this).val()) != -1){
            // found usa
            $('#center').val($('#center > option:first-child').val());
        }
        else if(uk.indexOf($(this).val()) != -1){
            //found uk
            $('#center').val($('#center > option:last-child').val());
        }
    });
});
```

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/PjVL6/6/)

Comment: Did you include jquery in your page?

Comment: Put it on your head tag <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

Comment: Sorry! I'm working. But it would be ok if you mail your page to me hicurin@gmail.com. I'll fix that for you!

Comment: Yes sir! It has a lot of ways to do that. So just talk about full what you want to do. We will discuss how to do it better

Comment: Thanks for reply, i just need to add few more to 'USA,uk...n' more option and make better.Please see